# Como separar uma base de séries temporal em periodos

Tags: r, séries-temporais

Eu tenho uma base de série temporal. Na base tem informação de consumo de ração de suínos (segue abaixo com informação de somente um dia e um animal). Tem uma coluna com a identificação do animal, dia e hora do dia que o animal consumiu a ração. Na coluna das horas eu precisava que fosse de 0 a 23, e nas horas que o animal não consumiu ficasse como consumo zero. Depois disso eu preciso calcular o consumo total a cada seis horas dentro de cada dia. Ou seja na tabela final teria somente o consumo total das 0 as 5, 6 as 11, 12 as 17 e 18 as 23 horas.

```
    X Animal Dia Hora Consumo
1   1      5   1    1   89.96
2   2      5   1    1   44.98
3   3      5   1    1   74.97
4   4      5   1    2  134.95
5   5      5   1    2   14.99
6   6      5   1    2   59.98
7   7      5   1    9  419.83
8   8      5   1    9   59.98
9   9      5   1    9   74.97
10 10      5   1    9   29.99
11 11      5   1   11   29.99
12 12      5   1   11  194.92
13 13      5   1   13  119.95
14 14      5   1   13   29.99
15 15      5   1   14   59.98
16 16      5   1   16  254.90
17 17      5   1   18  179.93
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Este problema pode ser resolvido com os pacotes `tidyr` e `dplyr`.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

dados.completos <- dados %>%
  select(-X) %>%
  complete(Hora=0:23, Animal, Dia, fill = list(Consumo = 0))
```

O código acima remove a coluna `X`, pois o problema original não a cita. A seguir, a função `complete` determina todos os valores possíveis para as horas, dizendo para completar os casos sem observações com 0, através do argumento `fill`. Tudo está salvo dentro do objeto `dados.completos`:

```
dados.completos %>% print(n=Inf)
# A tibble: 33 x 4
    Hora Animal   Dia Consumo
   <int>  <int> <int>   <dbl>
 1     0      5     1    0.00
 2     1      5     1   89.96
 3     1      5     1   44.98
 4     1      5     1   74.97
 5     2      5     1  134.95
 6     2      5     1   14.99
 7     2      5     1   59.98
 8     3      5     1    0.00
 9     4      5     1    0.00
10     5      5     1    0.00
11     6      5     1    0.00
12     7      5     1    0.00
13     8      5     1    0.00
14     9      5     1  419.83
15     9      5     1   59.98
16     9      5     1   74.97
17     9      5     1   29.99
18    10      5     1    0.00
19    11      5     1   29.99
20    11      5     1  194.92
21    12      5     1    0.00
22    13      5     1  119.95
23    13      5     1   29.99
24    14      5     1   59.98
25    15      5     1    0.00
26    16      5     1  254.90
27    17      5     1    0.00
28    18      5     1  179.93
29    19      5     1    0.00
30    20      5     1    0.00
31    21      5     1    0.00
32    22      5     1    0.00
33    23      5     1    0.00
```

Isto posto, basta separar as observações presentes dentro de dados completos em grupos de 6 horas. Para isto, eu usei a função `%/%`, que ao ser aplicada em `a %/% b`, calcula a divisão inteira de `a` por `b`. Assim,

```
dados.completos %>%
  mutate(Periodo = Hora %/% 6) %>%
  group_by(Periodo) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(Consumo))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
  Periodo  Total
    <dbl>  <dbl>
1       0 419.83
2       1 809.68
3       2 464.82
4       3 179.93
```

em que `Periodo` é o período do dia quando ocorreu o consumo. Período 0 é entre 0 e 5 horas; período 1 entre 6 e 11, e assim por diante.

---

**Edição realizada após [este comentário do OP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/236403/como-separar-uma-base-de-s%C3%A9ries-temporal-em-periodos#comment484371_236516)**

Para obter os resultados agrupados por `Animal`, `Dia` e `Periodo`, faça

```
dados.totais %>% mutate(Periodo = Hora %/% 6) %>%
  group_by(Hora, Animal, Dia, Periodo) %>%
  summarise(Total = sum(Consumo)) %>%
  print(n=Inf)
```

Comment: Olá Marcus! A primeira parte ficou perfeito, era exatemente o que eu queria. Mas a segunda na verdade eu preciso manter tabela, ou seja continuar com as colunas, Hora, Animal, Dia e agora também Periodo e Total(Consumo). É Possivel fazer isso?

Comment: Preciso continuar com o data.frame: Hora, Animal, Dia e agora também Periodo e Total (Consumo)

Comment: Veja a edição que fiz na resposta. Se o problema foi resolvido, [considere aceitar a resposta dada](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1078/como-e-por-que-aceitar-uma-resposta).